Domain configuration while setting cookie in Virtual Directory Endpoint vs Direct Endpoint
Having two urls

secure.test.site.com/login/autologin
secure.test.site.com/sessionlogin

First url is using virtual endpoint /login and second is using direct endpoint. Both are creating AUTHASPX session cookie but against different domain. secure.test.site.com/login/autologin for .secure.test.site.com domain and secure.test.site.com/sessionlogin for .test.site.com domain.
Why?

By using a more restrictive domain in endpoints that require higher security (such as automatic login), you can reduce the risk of sessions being intercepted maliciously. At the same time, using session cookies on a broader domain (such as .test.site.com) ensures that sessions are shared between users across the entire site.

But, using Request.Host.Url while configuring domain when setting cookie, not using any other explicit way of hard-code domain assignment

Using Request.Host.Url dynamically to set cookie domains is a flexible approach, but the observed differences likely stem from additional endpoint-specific logic or configurations. By intentionally setting more restrictive domains for higher security endpoints and broader domains for general session sharing, the application balances security and usability. Sorry, I'm not an expert in this area.
